# Why does this shiny app give the error that something "can only be done from inside a reactive expression"

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make my first shinyapp application. But I get this error:  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
I suspect there is an issue with that if. 
This is My code:

```
#install.packages("shinythemes")
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(caret)
#library(tree)
library(rattle)

heart=read.csv("Heart3.csv",header = TRUE)
heart=heart[complete.cases(heart),]

#checking missing values
#sum(is.na(heart))
# removing missing values
heart=heart[complete.cases(heart),]

    #create training/test split
    set.seed(345)
    train.index=createDataPartition(heart[,ncol(heart)],p=0.7,list=FALSE)
    train=heart[train.index,]
    test=heart[-train.index,]


    # Define UI for random distribution app ----
    ui <- fluidPage(
        # theme of the app
        theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),   #slate
        # App title ----
        titlePanel("Classification Alghoritms GC3"),

        # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
        sidebarLayout(

            # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
            sidebarPanel(
                helpText("Classify heart deaseses based on
                   decision tree or random forest"),
                radioButtons(inputId = "algorithm",
                             label= "Choose an algorithm",
                             choices = c("Decision Tree",
                                         "Random Forest"),
                             selected = "Decision Tree"),

                # Input: Select whether you want a decision tree or a random forest ----
                #radioButtons("option", "Type:",
                #c("Decision Tree" = "dt",
                #"Random Forest" = "rf")),


                # br() element to introduce extra vertical spacing ----
                #br(),

                # Input: Slider for the values to generate ----
                sliderInput("ff", "Fold:",
                            value = 10,
                            min = 1,
                            max = 50,
                            step = 1),

                sliderInput("rr", "Repeats:",
                            value = 3,
                            min = 1,
                            max = 50,
                            step=1),

                sliderInput("cpr", "cp:",
                            min = 0.01,
                            max = 0.1,
                            value=c(0.01,0.03),
                            step=0.01)
            ),

            # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
            mainPanel(
                #plotOutput(outputId = "plot"),
                # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
                tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                            tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
                            tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                            tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
                )# tabsetPanel

            )# main panel
        )# sidebar panel
    )# sidebar layout



    # Define server logic for random distribution app ----
    server <- function(input, output) {
        if(input$algorithm == "Random Forest"){
            outuput$plot<- function () renderPlot({
                fitcontrol=trainControl(
                    method ="repeatedcv",
                    number = input$ff,
                    repeats = input$rr)
                set.seed(324)
                cpGrid=expand.grid(cp=input$cpr)
                rfFit = train(AHD~. , data=train, method="rf", metric="Accuracy",
                              trControl=fitControl, tuneGrid=cpGrid)
                plot(rFit)
            })
        }
        if(input$algorithm == "Decision Tree"){
            output$plot <- function() renderPlot({
                # decision tree 
                fitcontrol=trainControl(method="repeatedcv",
                                        number=input$ff,
                                        repeats = input$rr)
                set.seed(1)
                cpGrid=expand.grid(cp=input$cpr)
                heart.rparts=train(train[,-ncol(heart)],
                                   train[,ncol(heart)],
                                   method = "rpart",
                                   tuneGrid = cpGrid,
                                   trControl = fitcontrol)
                #heart.rpart
                #plot(heart.rpart$finalModel)
                #text(heart.rpart$finalModel, cex=0.8)

                fancyRpartPlot(heart.rparts$finalModel) })
        }
    }


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: `renderPlot` itself is reactive, so you should put the if/else statement for `input$algorithm` *inside* `renderPlot` and it will re-evaluate every time `input$algorithm` changes.  As for the `function()` arguments, I don't think those are necessary.

Comment: Move your `if (input$algorithm == )` statements to **inside** the `renderPlot()`. You should only have one `output$plot <-  renderPlot({ })`.

Comment: @MrFlick actually I think he could keep both of ```output$plot <- renderPlot({ })``` if he puts the ```if``` conditions in an ```observe``` environment. However, he needs to remove ```function()``` from ```output$plot <- function() renderPlot({ })```